# TFS Ignores some file while getting The Branches

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a weird problem where TFS2015 checkout Everything Except a specific folder in the repository.
[image]

The WebSite folder is created on the agent but everything under it is completely ignored on both Branch both Dev and Main.

There is no .tfsignore or other files .files in any of the subfolder in the branch in fact is only a website .sln and some php/js scripts.

Here is the configuration for the build :

[image]

Comment: Could you manually check out these files and folders in both Main and Dev branch?

Comment: I can checkout the files locally (on my workstation) it works. But, the Agent still ignore completely the folder.

Comment: I've gived acces to another Person, and instead of seeing the whole WMS.WebSite\Sources\** files he only see an empty WMS.WebSite folder. It seem's like WMS.Website is using the Permission of another project. (it was in another project to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf permission command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command) to list all permission such as

`tf permission /server:<servername> <folder path in TFS>`

To check whether the some demand permissions are missing with your agent account.